# Remove features without lose functionality

Tags: 6, features

I'm working on a project where in the past was added a lot of features and was did in a way where right now a lot of them has a lot of circular dependencies and conflicts.

I want to start again, delete all the features, create new ones and avoid to each of them make conflicts with another.

My question is, how i can "remove" the features but not lose the changes to they did it on the project?, in other words how i can move the configuration "in code" into the database? for i able to remove the feature but preserve the configuration in the site?

I'm using Drupal 6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Features Tools Module](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) to disable a features module while leaving the functionality that was provided by the feature in place.

Instructions provided by [autopoietic](http://drupal.org/user/271093) [here](http://drupal.org/node/582674#comment-6163176).

> 1. First BACKUP YOUR DATABASE
> 2. backup your feature (files) if you would like to use it again.
> 3. Once installed, go to the 'recreate' page for a feature, uncheck all of the features
>      components
> 4. In order to save the elements to the DB you need to go to the admin/build/features/unlink
>      page, check the element you need to import and submit.
> 5. Now click on the 'Safe autocreate' button to recreate and replace the feature with an empty
>      version.
> 6. You can now disable the module without affecting your site configfuration.

These instructions note that "if you are using D6 there is an extra step" which I have added (step 4 above).