# Features - Is there a way to push changes back into the database

Tags: 7, database, features

I have a fairly good understanding of the way that features works:

- Make changes to your test site.
- Create a feature which contains the changes.
- Copy the new module (which was created by features) to live.
- activate the new module.
- Verify that the changes now exist on the live site.

This works great, but is there a way to take the changes that are contained in the new feature module and move them into the live database?  My goal is to reduce the number of active modules I have on my live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the module generated by Features has been activated and the status on the overview page reads "Default" **the changes are in the database**. "Default" means that the database configuration matches the configuration defined in the module. (The status "overridden" indicates that the module generated by Features does **not** match the database configuration.

I think what you want to ask is, "How can I disable a Feature-generated module without losing the configuration that it provided?", [which has been asked on this site before](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59876/remove-features-without-lose-functionality/60253#60253).

Comment: When you activate a feature module, are the changes contained in that feature module added to the database?  If so, then are those changes reverted when you deactivate a feature?

Comment: "When you activate a feature module, are the changes contained in that feature module added to the database?" **Yes.** "are those changes reverted when you deactivate a feature?" **Yes.** From the [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/582674) "_By design, disabling the feature module is supposed to also disable all the functionality that was defined by it. That is, remove node types that were created by it, etc._"

Comment: I obviously did not dig into the documentation that deeply.  I assumed that changes were implemented via code on each page load.

Comment: Common misunderstanding in my experience.

Comment: Just wondering: With the changes pushed to the database, is there a chance that another process could change the features' changes (Which might cause problems when you revert or update you feature?)

Comment: Yes. If a user or module change some configuration defined by a Features module, the Feature will have a status of "Overridden" on the overview page indicating that the database configuration has been overridden by something and no longer matches the configuration defined in the module. At that point, you can "Revert" the configuration which will attempt to bring the database configuration back in line with what is defined in the module.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. Some elements in a Feature don't get put into the database when you enable them (such as Views, Panel variants). the only items in a Feature that are added to the database upon enabling are pseudo exportables such as fields and content types. Also, if you enable a Feature containing a pseudo exportable, it will NOT be removed. E.g. if a Feature contains a View and a content type, when you disable the Feature the View will be removed, but the content type will not unless you write an install file with your own removal routines.